Horror movie with an alien parasite-infected woman with a circular saw in her stomach
I think it is an horror movie from the 90's but I can't tell for sure.
Near the end of the movie, in a house's backyard at night, near a swimming pool, there was a woman infected with an alien parasite which would lure a guy into kissing her. When they kissed she would try to kill him with a circular saw attached to its stomach (the saw was hidden inside her abdomen I think). However the guy would be able to cause the parasite to leave the woman's body (the parasite had the form of a black snake) and it would fall into the pool and start swimming in order to flee. This is all I can remember.

was it english spoken? color? any other details about the actors / characters?

Color. I watched it dubbed, but judging from its looks it was an English spoken movie, possibly American. I'm sorry I can't remember other details.

The Kiss  from 1988 has a black, parasitic creature hiding in a woman. At the end of the film the parasite's host is stabbed with a garden tool in a swimming pool while attacking a man at night. The black parasite worm attempts to swim away but is killed by an explosion. 

Looks very familiar! The black cat and also the infected woman making a ritual... My memories are a bit mixed up but I'm sure that's it! Thank you so very much!!!

Possibly, Species? It's made in 1995, one small difference being that the woman herself was an alien, kissing the man in the hot tub (?) she was trying to get him to impregnate her.
